# How to get list of all Types (fully qualified) created during application start up

Tags: .net, windows, performance

I'm wrestling with the cold-start performance of an application which happens to be a mix of .NET and COM.  By cold-start I mean starting the application after a reboot of the machine (which happens frequently on the deployed platform of Panasonic Toughbooks).

The cold start takes about 3 times as long as the warm start (110 seconds vs 35 seconds).

Using process monitor I have determined that the main difference between cold and warm start up is in the time taken to access dlls - mostly from the GAC, but also from Windows\microsoft.net and a few other folders.

I have reviewed the following related postings and actually implemented some of the suggestions:

- CLR Assembly Loading - Cold Start Performance Issue
  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/clr/thread/5d6444e6-9348-48da-b9f0-2eec4b933665

  [How to preload .net assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990197/how-to-preload-net-assemblies)

  Determining .NET Assembly and Method References
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163641.aspx

The upshot seems to be that I need to get either the IL assemblies or their native images "pre-loaded" into the system cache.  [I understand there's no guarantee they'll still be there when the application is actually started, and also that this will likely increase the boot time.]  According to some of the above posts this is an approach taken by Acrobat reader and Microsoft office.

My complication is that the third-party libraries being used are very large, so it's not practical to pre-load *all* the types in *all* the referenced assemblies.  I just want to load the types that are actually being loaded during application start-up.  So how do I identify just those types and their containing assemblies?

Another approach I am considering is to somehow start (and subequently kill) the app in the "background", but not sure if this can be done with a windows app.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After further research an suggestions from colleagues:

One way I've found to obtain such a list is via dotTracePerformance application by Jet Brains.

But I also found that at least some of this info is already contained in the "prefetch" file associated with the application under the folder C:\Windows\Prefetch.  These are binary files but one can use a tool like winPrefetchView to view the contents.

Unfortunately by default Windows only records the first few seconds of application startup in the prefetch file.  This time is configured in the registry, but (as discussed in the post [Windows XP prefetcher registry values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342075/windows-xp-prefetcher-registry-values)) the interpretation of this binary key is unclear.

I had the idea of somehow forcing a prefetch for the app at system startup, but haven't found a way to do this via the win api.  (Several hacks along these lines have not made a significant difference.)

In any case I have an answer to my original posting.

Comment: If this answers your question then you should accept is answer